# Create OSGI bundle from plain java maven project

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-servicemix

I've got maven project (non Spring one), what should I change inside my pom.xml to build jar to be executable by SMX/OSGI container. I've used felix plugin for spring projects like this:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <instructions>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>
          ${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}
        </Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Bundle-Name>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
        <Bundle-Activator>
          com.project.SpringBootBundleActivator
        </Bundle-Activator>
        <Export-Package>
          com.project
        </Export-Package>
        <Import-Package>
          com.project
          !org.springframework.*,
          !sun.*,
          !org.apache.tools.*,
          *;resolution:=optional
        </Import-Package>
        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile</Embed-Dependency>
        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
      </instructions>
      <buildDirectory>target/deploy</buildDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

It's working fine, but I cannot figure it out for non spring classes, cause what it does right now. It's trigger activation class with annotation @SpringBootApplication and allows me to deploy my app inside SMX.
What I would like to achieve is, instead of using Spring classes, use some camelContext.xml, that's got  and  inside and just define some beans from my custom classes inside it. For example,  and use method of this class in routes, but when I'm trying installing this classes there is problem with installing bundle inside of the contener. Error is related with OSGI R3 not supported.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question, but this is a simple camel osgi blueprint that generate a jar that is deployed in karaf deploy directory and works ok for me... https://github.com/wagnermarques/camel-routes-with-karaf/tree/main/bundles/blueprint-osgi-camel-bundles/processadordearquivos